# ClassCastException while assigning values to bundle

Tags: java, android

I am getting error while loading the bundle. I have checked all the initialization and casting but not able to resolve this. 
Please see the reference:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle.containsKey("MEASUREMENT_DATA")) {
    body_scaleMeasurement = bundle.getParcelable("MEASUREMENT_DATA");
    evaluate_info();
}
```

The code for body _scaleMeasurement

```
package model;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class BodyScaleMeasurement implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("client_platform_version")
    private String client_platform_version;
    @SerializedName("client_build_number")

    @SerializedName("client_platform_data")
    private Client_platform_data client_platform_data;
    @SerializedName("ble_device_data")
    private Ble_device_data ble_device_data;


    private transient boolean is_synchronized;

    public BodyScaleMeasurement() {
    }

    public BodyScaleMeasurement(String id, String client_platform_version, int client_build_number,  Client_platform_data client_platform_data, Ble_device_data ble_device_data, boolean is_synchronized) {
        this.id = id;
        this.client_platform_version = client_platform_version;
        this.client_build_number = client_build_number;

        this.client_platform_data = client_platform_data;
        this.ble_device_data = ble_device_data;

        this.is_synchronized = is_synchronized;

    }

    public boolean is_synchronized() {
        return is_synchronized;
    }

    public void setIs_synchronized(boolean is_synchronized) {
        this.is_synchronized = is_synchronized;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getClient_platform_version() {
        return client_platform_version;
    }

    public void setClient_platform_version(String client_platform_version) {
        this.client_platform_version = client_platform_version;
    }

    public int getClient_build_number() {
        return client_build_number;
    }

    public void setClient_build_number(int client_build_number) {
        this.client_build_number = client_build_number;
    }



    public Client_platform_data getClient_platform_data() {
        return client_platform_data;
    }

    public void setClient_platform_data(Client_platform_data client_platform_data) {
        this.client_platform_data = client_platform_data;
    }

    public Ble_device_data getBle_device_data() {
        return ble_device_data;
    }

    public void setBle_device_data(Ble_device_data ble_device_data) {
        this.ble_device_data = ble_device_data;
    }



    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.client_platform_version);
        dest.writeInt(this.client_build_number);

        dest.writeParcelable(this.client_platform_data, 0);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.ble_device_data, 0);

        dest.writeByte(is_synchronized ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
    }

    protected BodyScaleMeasurement(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readString();
        this.client_platform_version = in.readString();
        this.client_build_number = in.readInt();

        this.client_platform_data = in.readParcelable(Client_platform_data.class.getClassLoader());
        this.ble_device_data = in.readParcelable(Ble_device_data.class.getClassLoader());

        this.is_synchronized = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<BodyScaleMeasurement> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<BodyScaleMeasurement>() {
        public BodyScaleMeasurement createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new BodyScaleMeasurement(source);
        }

        public BodyScaleMeasurement[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BodyScaleMeasurement[size];
        }
    };
}
```

This is the error which i get. Please refer the image I have attached.

[image: error image]

Comment: Which line is BodyScaleMeasurement.java:338?

Comment: this.ble_device_data = in.readParcelable(Ble_device_data.class.getClassLoader());

Comment: @shmosel please check the comment

Comment: What happened to `client_build_number`?

Comment: That's work fine. Its giving error on ble for casting. Dunno

Comment: It's missing from the class.

Comment: Nope. I Actually removed extra fields to make the class shorter. Nothing is linked. and build no. is present though

Answer (score 0):

It was happening because I changed the type of other variables from `double` to `int`. It was not expected though, but I am myself not understaning it. I reverted the changes in which the conversion was done.

Also, there was change in values too after conversion. For example : if i was sending 50 to bundle with a key. It was being setted as some negative integer.

Comment: This might help some people in there problem. Please refer this.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that the `Client_platform_data implements Parcelable` and has 
`Parcelable.Creator<Ble_device_data>` ?

Comment: This is not the answer. If you want to ask OP a question, use "add a comment" below the question. If you lack reputation do that, work on your reputation score first by answering other questions.